# Start separate process to run Java program using same JRE

Tags: java

I want to start a separate process from my java program to run another java program using same JRE that the current java program is executing in. Normally, I could get the path to the java executable using `System.getProperty`, but the java program is running in a bundled jre (Mac app package) which doesn't actually contain a java executable. Therefore, I'm wondering if there is there any API to directly run a Java program in a separate process?

Answer (score 1):

Javapackager from Java version 9 on includes the bundler argument `-strip-native-commands` which leaves the executables in the bundled JRE. Just include the option:

```
-Bstrip-native-commands=false
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is public hosted here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

and the information you are looking for cons from the `System` utility class:

All available properties are listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--

The current JVMs location is available via "java.home".

So what your looking for is:

```
 String javaPath = new File( System.getProperty("java.home"),"bin/java").absolutePath();
```

Comment: As I mention, the bundled jre doesn't actually contain a java executable

Comment: @SimonZhu *"As I mention, the bundled jre doesn't actually contain a java executable"* - This does not matter. The program was started with a JRE installed on your system, and from within java this property **always** points to the *currently running* Java installation, regadless of where your system wide, or shell specific `$JAVA_HOME` points to.

Comment: No, the program runs in the bundled jre, which doesn't contain a java executable. In other words, `System.getProperty("java.home") + "bin/java"` does not exist.

Comment: @SimonZhu *"No, the program runs in the bundled jre, which doesn't contain a java executable."* that's nonsense. *no java executable -> no JRE* end of message!

Comment: I suggest you look up embedded JRE's. If you want, you can take a look at the application in question [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Good luck finding the java executable.

Answer (score 0):

This may give a better picture.

Get the Java executable using below.

```
System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java"
```

ReConstruct the class path,

```
((URLClassLoader() Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getURL()
```

From here, you can start the new process using

```
Process.exec(javaExecutable, "-classpath", urls.join(":"), CLASS_WIH_MAIN)
```

Comment: As I said to Timothy and I mention in my question, the bundled jre doesn't contain an executable java. The filepath returned by `System.getProperty("java.home")` does not even contain a `bin` folder.